# How to reach a hidden Python function with HTML injection in a web app?

Tags: web-application, injection, python

I was doing a web app CTF problem which has a web form which is vulnerable to HTML code injection. The goal of the problem is to reach a hidden Python function in that web app. It is a Python based web app but the underlying framework is not known. How can I leverage HTML injection to call the Python function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since HTML injection affects the client only but the python function is server side you cannot reach it directly. But your HTML injection might change the requests sent by an authorized user and this way you might cause changes in the execution of the server side application which ultimately leads to the call of the hidden python function. Useful injections are for example changes of existing HTML forms, adding new forms, links or images which all ultimately result in requests to the server as authenticated user (i.e. include the cookie).

Example:

```
<form action=/do_something>          
<form action=/call_hidden_function>  <!-- injected this line -->
...
<input type=hidden name=crsf_protection_token value=...>
<input type=submit value="Submit form">
</form>
```